# Стенд-ап українською

Tags: вибір-слова

Цікавить чи є відповідник до сучасного слова "[стендап](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%B0%D0%BF_(%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%80))"(сольний гумористичний виступ перед живою аудиторією), яке походить з англійської мови, однак часто вживається сьогодні нашими співвітчизниками. Сайт Словотвір пропонує такі варіант як "[гуморесник](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/stendap-kamedi)", однак такого слова немає в СУМі, є лише "[гумореска](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghumoreska)" (невелика музична п'єса жартівливого, гумористичного характеру). Це слово не підходить, бо не завжди стенд-ап має музичний супровід.

Отож, чи є в українській мові якісь відповідники до даного слова?